# stream a zip created on the fly with play 2.5 and akka stream with backpressure

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I would like to stream a zip created on the fly (without putting it entirely in memory) with the play-framework 2.5 using akka stream with backpressure. Here my code, with a small zip created on the fly(16KB).When the client download the url associated with the action, the download does not start.

```
import java.util.zip.{ ZipEntry, ZipOutputStream, GZIPOutputStream }
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.util.ByteString
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import java.io.{ BufferedOutputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream }
import scala.concurrent.{ Promise, Future }
import akka.stream.OverflowStrategy
class ZipController extends Controller {

  def getStreamedZip = Action {
    val source: Source[ByteString, java.io.OutputStream] = StreamConverters.asOutputStream()
    val result = source.mapMaterializedValue(x => {
      val zip = new ZipOutputStream(x)
      (0 to 100).map { i =>
        zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("test-zip/README-" + i + ".txt"))
        zip.write("This is the line:\n".map(_.toByte).toArray)
        zip.closeEntry()
      }
      zip.close
      x
    })
    Ok.chunked(result).withHeaders(
      "Content-Type" -> "application/zip",
      "Content-Disposition" -> "attachment; filename=test.zip"
    )
  }


}
```

Basically I want to stream a zip file of 2GB on a 1 GB memory server. And this zip will be composed of files of about 15MB. Is it possible to write the zip without loading entirely each file in memory ?  If let say 3 clients download  the zip  at 1MB/second speed. Approximatively how much memory these downloads will take ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you might be hitting this: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6743

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation sourced at https://gist.github.com/kirked/412b5156f94419e71ce4a84ec1d54761

```
/* License: MIT */

import com.typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j.StrictLogging
import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, InputStream, IOException}
import java.util.zip.{ZipEntry, ZipOutputStream}
import play.api.libs.iteratee.{Enumeratee, Enumerator}
import scala.concurrent.{Future, ExecutionContext}

/**
 * Play iteratee-based reactive zip-file generation.
 */
object ZipEnumerator extends StrictLogging {

  /**
   * A source to zip.
   * 
   * @param  filepath The zip-file path at which to store the data.
   * @param  stream   The data stream provider.
   */
  case class Source(filepath: String, stream: () => Future[Option[InputStream]])

  /**
   * Given sources, returns an Enumerator that feeds a zip-file of the source contents.
   */
  def apply(sources: Iterable[Source])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = {
    val resolveSources: Enumerator[ResolvedSource] = Enumerator.unfoldM(sources) { sources =>
      sources.headOption match {
        case None                                 => Future(None)
        case Some(Source(filepath, futureStream)) =>
          futureStream().map { _.map(stream => (sources.tail, ResolvedSource(filepath, stream)) ) }
      }
    }

    val buffer = new ZipBuffer(8192)

    val writeCentralDirectory = Enumerator.generateM(Future {
      if (buffer.isClosed) None
      else {
        buffer.close
        Some(buffer.bytes)
      }
    })

    resolveSources &> zipeach(buffer) andThen writeCentralDirectory
  }


  private def zipeach(buffer: ZipBuffer)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Enumeratee[ResolvedSource, Array[Byte]] = {
    Enumeratee.mapConcat[ResolvedSource] { source =>
      buffer.zipStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(source.filepath))
      var done = false

      def entryDone: Unit = {
        done = true
        buffer.zipStream.closeEntry
        source.stream.close
      }

      def restOfStream: Stream[Array[Byte]] = {
        if (done) Stream.empty
        else {
          while (!done && !buffer.full) {
            try {
              val byte = source.stream.read
              if (byte == -1) entryDone
              else buffer.zipStream.write(byte)
            }
            catch {
              case e: IOException =>
                logger.error(s"reading/zipping stream [${source.filepath}]", e)
                entryDone
            }
          }
          buffer.bytes #:: restOfStream
        }
      }

      restOfStream
    }
  }


  private case class ResolvedSource(filepath: String, stream: InputStream)


  private class ZipBuffer(capacity: Int) {
    private val buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream(capacity)
    private var closed = false
    val zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(buf)

    def close(): Unit = {
      if (!closed) {
        closed = true
        reset
        zipStream.close   // writes central directory
      }
    }

    def isClosed = closed

    def reset: Unit = buf.reset

    def full: Boolean = buf.size >= capacity

    def bytes: Array[Byte] = {
      val result = buf.toByteArray
      reset
      result
    }
  }
}
```

The usage looks something like this:

```
val s3 = ...
val sources = items.map(item => ZipEnumerator.Source(item.filename, { () => s3.getInputStream(item.storagePath) }))
Ok.chunked(ZipEnumerator(sources))(play.api.http.Writeable.wBytes).withHeaders(
            CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/zip",
            CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"attachment; filename=MyFiles.zip; filename*=UTF-8''My%20Files.zip"
          )
```

Comment: Akka streams implementation here: https://gist.github.com/kirked/03c7f111de0e9a1f74377bf95d3f0f60

Comment: The Akka implementation in your gist fails for me (see comment on gist)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the above methods didn't work for me. Here's my code that works for zipping files on the fly and download them via play framework.

```
import java.io.{BufferedOutputStream, ByteArrayInputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream}
import java.util.zip.{ZipEntry, ZipOutputStream}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{StreamConverters}
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

class HomeController extends Controller {
  def single() = Action {
                         Ok.sendFile(
                           content = new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\a.csv"),
                           fileName = _ => "a.csv"
                         )
                       }

  def zip() = Action {
                     Ok.chunked(StreamConverters.fromInputStream(fileByteData)).withHeaders(
                       CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/zip",
                       CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"attachment; filename = test.zip"
                     )
                   }

  def fileByteData(): ByteArrayInputStream = {
    val fileList = List(
      new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\a.csv"),
      new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\b.csv")
    )

    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(baos))

    try {
      fileList.map(file => {
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.toPath.getFileName.toString))
        zos.write(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file))
        zos.closeEntry()
      })
    } finally {
      zos.close()
    }

    new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray)
  }
}
```

The basic idea for the zip() is converting files to `ByteArrayInputStream` and use `StreamConverter` to send it as chunked data.

Comment: That'll work for small files, but will fail with OutOfMemoryErrors on large files, as you're holding all of the data in memory. You're also not streaming the data from its source all the way out to the client.

Comment: @WeaponsGrade Thanks for pointing that out! I'm very new to this. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve? One of the requirements is that files can't be written to local disk.

Comment: See the answer above for a Play Iteratee solution, or the comment below it for Akka Streams solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since Alpakka 3.0.4, `akka-stream-alpakka-file` supports zip archives: https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/file.html#zip-archive