# zip-compress a List[Source[ByteString, NotUsed]] on the fly with Akka Streams

Tags: scala, playframework, compression, akka, akka-stream

I have a list of `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]` paired with filenames that come from an S3 bucket. These need to be zipped in constant memory and served in Play 2.6.

There is a somewhat similar question here: [stream a zip created on the fly with play 2.5 and akka stream with backpressure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780149/stream-a-zip-created-on-the-fly-with-play-2-5-and-akka-stream-with-backpressure)

with a relevant code snippet for Akka Streams (needed for Play 2.6+) here:

https://gist.github.com/kirked/03c7f111de0e9a1f74377bf95d3f0f60

I based my experiments so far on the gist above, however, the gist solves a different problem -- it streams the files from the disk by passing the graph stage an `InputStream`. There is, however, no safe way to transform my `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]` into an `InputStream`, so I cannot use the snippet as-is.

My experiment so far has been to change the input type from `() => InputStream` to `() => Source[ByteString, NotUsed]` and then consume it using `source.runForeach(...)`.

The bulk of my change is here:

```
override def onPush(): Unit = {
  val (filepath, source: StreamGenerator) = grab(in)
  buffer.startEntry(filepath)
  val src: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = source()
  val operation = src.runForeach(bytestring => {
    val byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytestring.toArray)
    emitMultiple(out, fileChunks(byteInputStream, buffer))
  })
  operation.onComplete {
    case _ => buffer.endEntry()
  }
  Await.ready(operation, 5.minute)
}
```

I know that this is blocking, but I am unsure whether or not it is allowed in this context.

How do I accomplish this in a safe way?

**EDIT**

I also tried this version which is much closer to the gist:

```
override def onPush(): Unit = {
  val (filepath, source: StreamGenerator) = grab(in)
  buffer.startEntry(filepath)
  val stream = source().runWith(StreamConverters.asInputStream(1.minute))
  currentStream = Some(stream)
  emitMultiple(out, fileChunks(stream, buffer), () => buffer.endEntry())
}
```

However, it yields an error with this stack trace:

> [ERROR] [11/27/2017 09:26:38.428]
>   [alpakka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]
>   [akka://alpakka/user/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-0-0-headSink] Error in
>   stage [com.company.productregistration.services.s3.StreamedZip@7f573427]:
>   Reactive stream is terminated, no reads are possible
>   java.io.IOException: Reactive stream is terminated, no reads are
>   possible  at
>   akka.stream.impl.io.InputStreamAdapter.subscriberClosedException(InputStreamSinkStage.scala:117)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.io.InputStreamAdapter.executeIfNotClosed(InputStreamSinkStage.scala:125)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.io.InputStreamAdapter.read(InputStreamSinkStage.scala:144)
>     at
>   com.company.productregistration.services.s3.StreamedZip$$anon$2.result$1(StreamedZip.scala:99)
>     at
>   com.company.productregistration.services.s3.StreamedZip$$anon$2.$anonfun$fileChunks$1(StreamedZip.scala:105)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1169)   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1159)    at
>   scala.collection.immutable.StreamIterator.$anonfun$next$1(Stream.scala:1058)
>     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.StreamIterator$LazyCell.v$lzycompute(Stream.scala:1047)
>     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.StreamIterator$LazyCell.v(Stream.scala:1047)
>     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.StreamIterator.hasNext(Stream.scala:1052)
>     at
>   akka.stream.stage.GraphStageLogic$EmittingIterator.onPull(GraphStage.scala:911)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPull(GraphInterpreter.scala:506)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:412)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:571)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.init(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:541)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.tryInit(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:659)
>     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.preStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:707)
>     at akka.actor.Actor.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:522)     at
>   akka.actor.Actor.aroundPreStart$(Actor.scala:522)     at
>   akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundPreStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:650)
>     at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:591)     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:484)    at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)     at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)  at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)     at
>   akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)     at
>   akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

**EDIT2**
If I don't set `currentStream = Some(stream)`, I don't get the above error. Furthermore, it does indeed work for some combinations of files. I have a *larger* file of around 20 megabytes which, if I put it as the last source, corrupts my zip file. If I put it anywhere else in the list of sources, everything works correctly.

Below is a complete listing of my current graph stage implementation:

```
import java.io.{ByteArrayInputStream, InputStream, OutputStream}

import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.stream.stage._
import akka.util.{ByteString, ByteStringBuilder}

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext}
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

//scalastyle:off
class StreamedZip(bufferSize: Int = 64 * 1024)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext,
                                               mat: ActorMaterializer)
    extends GraphStage[FlowShape[StreamedZip.ZipSource, ByteString]] {

  import StreamedZip._

  val in: Inlet[ZipSource]    = Inlet("StreamedZip.in")
  val out: Outlet[ByteString] = Outlet("StreamedZip.out")
  override val shape          = FlowShape.of(in, out)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) with StageLogging {
      private val buffer                             = new ZipBuffer(bufferSize)
      private var currentStream: Option[InputStream] = None

      setHandler(
        out,
        new OutHandler {
          override def onPull(): Unit =
            if (isClosed(in)) {
              if (buffer.isEmpty) completeStage()
              else {
                buffer.close
                push(out, buffer.toByteString)
              }
            } else pull(in)

          override def onDownstreamFinish(): Unit = {
            closeInput()
            buffer.close
            super.onDownstreamFinish()
          }
        }
      )

      setHandler(
        in,
        new InHandler {
          override def onPush(): Unit = {
            val (filepath, source: StreamGenerator) = grab(in)
            buffer.startEntry(filepath)
            val stream = source().runWith(StreamConverters.asInputStream(1.minute))
            emitMultiple(out, fileChunks(stream, buffer), () => { buffer.endEntry() })
          }

          override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
            println("Updstream finish")
            closeInput()
            if (buffer.isEmpty) completeStage()
            else {
              buffer.close()
              if (isAvailable(out)) {
                push(out, buffer.toByteString)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      )

      private def closeInput(): Unit = {
        currentStream.foreach(_.close)
        currentStream = None
      }

      private def fileChunks(stream: InputStream, buffer: ZipBuffer): Iterator[ByteString] = {
        // This seems like a good trade-off between single-byte
        // read I/O performance and doubling the ZipBuffer size.
        //
        // And it's still a decent defense against DDOS resource
        // limit attacks.
        val readBuffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
        var done       = false

        def result: Stream[ByteString] =
          if (done) Stream.empty
          else {
            try {
              while (!done && buffer.remaining > 0) {
                val bytesToRead = Math.min(readBuffer.length, buffer.remaining)
                val count       = stream.read(readBuffer, 0, bytesToRead)
                if (count == -1) {
                  stream.close
                  done = true
                } else buffer.write(readBuffer, count)
              }
              buffer.toByteString #:: result
            } catch {
              case NonFatal(e) =>
                closeInput()
                throw e
            }
          }

        result.iterator
      }
    }
}

object StreamedZip {
  type ZipFilePath     = String
  type StreamGenerator = () => Source[ByteString, NotUsed]
  type ZipSource       = (ZipFilePath, StreamGenerator)

  def apply()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, mat: ActorMaterializer) = new StreamedZip()

}

class ZipBuffer(val bufferSize: Int = 64 * 1024) {
  import java.util.zip.{ZipEntry, ZipOutputStream}

  private var builder = new ByteStringBuilder()
  private val zip = new ZipOutputStream(builder.asOutputStream) {
    // this MUST ONLY be used after flush()!
    def setOut(newStream: OutputStream): Unit = out = newStream
  }
  private var inEntry = false
  private var closed  = false

  def close(): Unit = {
    endEntry()
    closed = true
    zip.close()
  }

  def remaining(): Int = bufferSize - builder.length

  def isEmpty(): Boolean = builder.isEmpty

  def startEntry(path: String): Unit =
    if (!closed) {
      endEntry()
      zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path))
      inEntry = true
    }

  def endEntry(): Unit =
    if (!closed && inEntry) {
      inEntry = false
      zip.closeEntry()
    }

  def write(byte: Int): Unit =
    if (!closed && inEntry) zip.write(byte)

  def write(bytes: Array[Byte], length: Int): Unit =
    if (!closed && inEntry) zip.write(bytes, 0, length)

  def toByteString(): ByteString = {
    zip.flush()
    val result = builder.result
    builder = new ByteStringBuilder()
    // set the underlying output for the zip stream to be the buffer
    // directly, so we don't have to copy the zip'd byte array.
    zip.setOut(builder.asOutputStream)
    result
  }
}
```

Comment: You may find this answer here useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47146187/49630

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the `ZipBuffer` from above and solve the overall problem using the akka stream DSL.

My solution looks as follows:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, SourceShape}
import akka.util.ByteString
import com.company.config.AWS
import org.log4s.getLogger

case class S3StreamingServiceLike(awsConf: AWS, s3Client: S3ClientAlpakka)(
    implicit sys: ActorSystem,
    mat: ActorMaterializer)
    extends S3StreamingService {

  private implicit class ConcatSyntax[T, U](source: Source[T, U]) {
    def ++[TT >: T, NotUsed](that: Source[SourceShape[TT], NotUsed]): Source[Any, U] = //scalastyle:ignore
      source.concat(that)
  }

  private val logger = getLogger

  private sealed trait ZipElement
  private case class FileStart(name: String, index: Int, outOf: Int) extends ZipElement
  private case class FileEnd(name: String, index: Int, outOf: Int)   extends ZipElement
  private case class FilePayload(byteString: ByteString)             extends ZipElement
  private case object EndZip                                         extends ZipElement

  private def payloadSource(filename: String) =
    s3Client.download(awsConf.s3BucketName, filename).map(FilePayload.apply)

  private def fileNameToZipElements(filename: String,
                                    index: Int,
                                    outOf: Int): Source[ZipElement, NotUsed] =
    Source.single(FileStart(filename, index, outOf)) ++
      payloadSource(filename) ++
      Source.single(FileEnd(filename, index, outOf))

  def streamFilesAsZip(filenames: List[String])(forUser: String): Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = {

    val zipBuffer = new ZipBuffer()

    val zipElementSource: Source[ZipElement, NotUsed] =
      Source(filenames.zipWithIndex).flatMapConcat {
        case (filename, index) => fileNameToZipElements(filename, index + 1, filenames.length)
      } ++ Source.single(EndZip)

    zipElementSource
      .map {
        case FileStart(name, index, outOf) =>
          logger.info(s"Zipping file #$index of $outOf with name $name for user $forUser")
          zipBuffer.startEntry(name)
          None
        case FilePayload(byteString) =>
          if (byteString.length > zipBuffer.remaining()) {
            throw new Exception(
              s"Bytestring size exceeded buffer size ${byteString.length} > ${zipBuffer.remaining}")
          }
          zipBuffer.write(byteString.toArray, byteString.length)
          Some(zipBuffer.toByteString())
        case FileEnd(name, index, outOf) =>
          logger.info(s"Finished zipping file #$index of $outOf with $name for user $forUser")
          zipBuffer.endEntry()
          Some(zipBuffer.toByteString())
        case EndZip =>
          zipBuffer.close()
          Some(zipBuffer.toByteString())
      }
      .collect {
        case Some(bytes) if bytes.length > 0 => bytes
      }
  }

}
```